# Как считать версию приложения из контейнера для метрики в Prometheus?

Tags: java, docker, непрерывная-интеграция, микросервисы, prometheus

У меня есть сервисы контейнерах, настроен CI/CD, мне нужно считывать версию приложения, которая каждый раз инкрементируется после нового билда и выводить в Prometheus.
Буду рад любым советам!

Comment: Процедура сборки может помещать версию в виде файла или переменной окружения в образ.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA как её вытащить?

Comment: Это все зависит от того как устроен CI и что вы используете. Обычно CI системы типа jenkins, teamcity и т.п. позволяют процессу сборки получить номер билда. Используйте его, т.е. пробрасывайте в Dockerfile и там или в файл сохраняйте или в переменную окружения.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю что конкретики не будет? Просто общими словами мне тоже понятно всё, реализовать не получается

Comment: Я же написал, что конкретный ответ зависит от того, какую систему CI вы используете. Вы этого в вопросе не написали, а таких систем много. В вопросе нет конкретики - поэтому и ответ нельзя дать.

Comment: teamcity. Но при билде в тимсити, предполагаю, будет заменяться версия указанная в помнике. вот её мне никак не удается вытащить в код, чтобы перейти к шагу запихивания в прометеус

Comment: Вам нужно добавить всю информацию в вопрос. Вот сейчас вы упомянули, что версия в pom файле. Как без этого можно дать конкретный ответ на вопрос? Опишите полностью как у вас делается билд, каким образом формируется версия, где хранится и т.д. Что ожидаете в результате. Модифицируйте вопрос кнопкой "править", а не комментарии.